# Graph with minimal cycle 5

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Let $ G(V,E)$ be a graph with $deg(v)\ge k,\forall v\in V$.

The graph $ G $ has a simple minimal cycle length of 5.(I.E the shortest cycle is of length 5)

Prove: $ |V|\ge k^2+1 $

I saw a solution via a proof by contradiction, however I tried proving this with induction on both $K$ and $n$ where $n=|V| $.

How does one approach this with induction? I tried adding an edge to every vertex with deg $k $  but I can't seem to find the implication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose a vertex $v$ and lets call this the base point. This point will have at least $k$ neighbouring points (call this set of points the first shell).
Now each of these points (in the first shell) will have a least $k-1$ neighbouring points ( call these points the second shell). All these points must be distinct (otherwise they will form a $4-$cycle). So ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mid V \mid \geq \underbrace{1}_{\text{the base point}} +\underbrace{k}_{\text{the first shell}} +\underbrace{k(k-1)}_{\text{the second shell}}.
\end{eqnarray*}